# google maps - centering on user location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map with hundreds of markers. I would like the map to center on the users location - preferably with a button click. Currently, I have it centering on page load but with one problem - it clears out all of the markers when it centers on location. I assume this is because of how I'm calling the script. The map container's id is 'map4'.

How can I make this script work without clearing the existing markers? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
var map;    // Google map object

// Initialize and display a google map
function Init()
{
    // HTML5/W3C Geolocation
    if ( navigator.geolocation )
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( UserLocation );
    // Default to Sherman Oaks
    else
        ShowLocation( 38.8951, -77.0367, "Sherman Oaks, CA" );
}

// Callback function for asynchronous call to HTML5 geolocation
function UserLocation( position )
{
    ShowLocation( position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, "This is your Location" );
}

// Display a map centered at the specified coordinate with a marker and InfoWindow.
function ShowLocation( lat, lng, title )
{
    // Create a Google coordinate object for where to center the map
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng );    

    // Map options for how to display the Google map
    var mapOptions = { zoom: 12, center: latlng  };

    // Show the Google map in the div with the attribute id 'map-canvas'.
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map4'), mapOptions);

    // Place a Google Marker at the same location as the map center 
    // When you hover over the marker, it will display the title
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker( { 
        position: latlng,     
        map: map,      
        title: title
    });

    // Create an InfoWindow for the marker
    var contentString = "<b>" + title + "</b>"; // HTML text to display in the InfoWindow
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow( { content: contentString } );

    // Set event to display the InfoWindow anchored to the marker when the marker is clicked.
    google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function() { infowindow.open( map, marker ); });
}

// Call the method 'Init()' to display the google map when the web page is displayed ( load event )
google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', Init );

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it seems you already have created a map, populated with markers AND THEN you want to center the VERY SAME map. If that's the case, your `ShowLocation()` function needs to be modified. The reason is that this line

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map4'), mapOptions);
```

creates a fresh new instance of map (replacing any existing map in that container, if the provided map container is the same).

So your problem is that you are creating and centering a new map, instead of just centering the old one.

Just modify the centering function to work with an existing map:

```
function ShowLocation( lat, lng, title , map)
{
    // Create a Google coordinate object for where to center the map
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng);    

    //Working with existing map instead of creating a new one
    map.setCenter(latlng);
    map.setZoom(12);

    // Place a Google Marker at the same location as the map center 
    // When you hover over the marker, it will display the title
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker( { 
        position: latlng,     
        map: map,      
        title: title
    });

    // Create an InfoWindow for the marker
    var contentString = "<b>" + title + "</b>"; // HTML text to display in the InfoWindow
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow( { content: contentString } );

    // Set event to display the InfoWindow anchored to the marker when the marker is clicked.
    google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function() { infowindow.open( map, marker ); });
}
```

And when calling the `ShowLocation` function, it's 4th parameter would be the `google.maps.Map` object you created when adding the markers. You cannot reference map only by knowing it's containing element's `id`, you need the reference for it.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct! I do have an existing map and want to center it on the users location automatically - or preferable with a click of a button.

Comment: So just find somewhere in your code where do you create the original map, which you then add markers to, something like: `map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map4')..` (but not in your  `ShowLocation` function). And then you have to use the very same `map` object with my provided `ShowLocation` function

Comment: I tried the code but now it's not centering on the map or showing the user location. It's not creating a new map - so that's a plus.  Maybe I'm not calling the map correct. The id should be 'map4' but I'm not sure where to enter that information.

Comment: I setup a link to the updated code. Let me know if you want to see the complete code with the markers. https://jsfiddle.net/pioneerdesign7/34qtobd9/#&togetherjs=wbVicAwzLi

Comment: I need to see the part of code which creates the original map and adds the markers. The map `id` isn't gonna help us, you need to get to the variable which points to the original map. Try to look for all lines of code containing `new google.maps.Map`

Comment: OK here's the entire code: https://jsfiddle.net/pioneerdesign7/34qtobd9/#run&togetherjs=wbVicAwzLi

I did see the code in there: var map4_map=new google.maps.Map(map4_canvas,map4_options);

Comment: The link did not take me to the entire code. Anyway, calling my function with `map4_map` as the 4th parameter should work: `ShowLocation( position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, "This is your Location",  map4_map);` . If you get error that `map` is undefined, just make it globally available, for example by removing `var` keyword from `var map4_map=new google.maps.Map(map4_canvas,map4_options);`

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help on this.